# Why does Time.deltaTime always return a constant value - and why does it differ from Time.unscaledDeltaTime when Timescale is set to 1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been having some strange problems lately so I decided to start a new project in Unity 2018.4, the project has a single monobehaviour:

```
public class TestTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int randLoop = UnityEngine.Random.Range(9999999, 999999999);
        for (int i = 0; i < randLoop; i++)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        string guiString = "Time: " + Time.time + "\r\n";
        guiString += "Unscaled time: " + Time.unscaledTime + "\r\n";
        guiString += "Timescale: " + Time.timeScale + "\r\n";
        guiString += "Time.deltaTime: " + Time.deltaTime + "\r\n";
        guiString += "Time.unscaledDeltaTime: " + Time.unscaledDeltaTime + "\r\n";
        GUI.Label(new Rect(25, 15, 800, 800), guiString);
    }
}
```

This loop causes the framerate to fluctuate between 0.5-3fps.

The expectation is that the GUI should show a rather high value for `Time.deltaTime`, and it should be the same as `Time.unscaledTime` because `Time.timeScale` is not changed from the default of 1.

However, `Time.time` crawls along at a very slow speed, `Time.deltaTime` stays at a fixed value of 0.1, and only the `Time.unscaledTime` values return valid data.

Surely `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` should always equal `Time.deltaTime` when Timescale is 1 - and surely Time.time should return the same value as `Time.unscaledTime` if Timescale has been 1 since the application started?

[image: OnGui ouput]

Note that these values are the same if they are stored in fields in the Update call rather than being called directly from OnGui.

Answer (score 0):

From Unity manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

> Do not rely on Time.deltaTime inside MonoBehaviour.OnGUI. Unity can
>   call OnGUI multiple times per frame. The application use the same
>   deltaTime value per call.

Comment: `unscaledTime` != `unscaledDeltaTime`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, time delta time is bullsniz. Its just 1 / the fixed update rate, which is only actually limited at the upper end. I don't care what they think it does, it doesn't. And fixed update doesn't work independently either when your framerate fluctuates. Low frame rate will stretch physics out, and extreme high framerate will gimp all your forces. It's best to develop for a target framerate and then optimize so that you can hit it on all devices you're targeting, then declare a target framerate in the script and set your fixed timestep to 1 / (a little under your target framerate) just to be safe. Every device that can run it smoothly will look the same. Underpowered devices won't.

EDIT---
Time delta time doesn't change in fixed update. Fixed update still has the problems I mentioned. You can run without vsync to see this. You can use the inverse of updates value for time delta time to smooth it out. But then you need to readjust your force modifiers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).